# cordova.file.dataDirectory is undefined

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

after six hours of searching the web my hope is to find an answer here on SO.

Platform: Windows,
Ionic Framework, 
Target Devices: Android/ iOS 7.1.2

I want to write a file in my application folder, so I used the cordova plugin
'cordova-plugin-file'.

inside app.js run-method:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  if (cordova.file === undefined)
    console.log("FILE IS UNDEFINED");
else
    console.log("IT WORKS! YEAH");
});
```

On Android the file-object is available and I can access cordova.file.dataDirectory. In iOS the file object is always undefined.

I'm logging the console via jsconsole.com

IOS File (.IPA) was build via ionic build ios - service. I don't have a mac here.

Any ideas?
Thank you!!

Comment: Where do you store the file ?
The storage are pretty different inIOS and Android.
Try reading up on this 
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

Comment: Before storing I have to define the locationpath via cordova.file.[IOS-Spezific-folder/ObjectName]. But unfortunately cordova.file is undefined, so it's impossible to define a path-

Official docs says "cordova.file.*" <- but file is undefined ..

Answer (score 2):

Reason:

cordova.file is undefined because the cordova-file-plugin is not loaded.

I've to use ionic's wrapper

"ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file"

INSTEAD OF

"cordova add cordova-plugin-file"

Then on the deploy process it will be injected to all available platforms (android / ios).

:)